# Find duplicates in "Array of objects" with different keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, duplicates, key-value

Given an array of objects. For example

```js
let letters= [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":7}, {"d":4,"c":21,"f":2}, {"g":34,"c":2} ]
```

I would like to find the keys which is in all three object is common. In this case c. On output I would like to see "c". The value doesn't matter now just the key. I know how to do it with identical keys (e.g id) but no idea with different ones. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let letters= [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":7}, {"d":4,"c":21,"f":2}, {"g":34,"c":2}]

let result = letters
.map(group => Object.keys(group))
.reduce((arr, v) => arr ? arr.filter(key => v.includes(key)) : v, null)

console.log(result)
```

this will give you all common keys in an array.

Comment: Watch out for that time complexity

Comment: Time complexity is O(n^3)

Answer (score 1):

1. Iterate the array of objects and build up a map of key counts
2. Filter that map down to counts equal to the number of elements in the array
3. Return the keys

```js
const letters = [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":7}, {"d":4,"c":21,"f":2}, {"g":34,"c":2}]

const counts = letters.reduce((map, o) => {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(key => {
    map.set(key, (map.get(key) ?? 0) + 1)
  })
  return map
}, new Map())

const duplicates = [...counts].filter(([ _, count ]) => count === letters.length)
  .map(([ key ]) => key)
  
console.info(duplicates)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const letters = [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":7}, {"d":4,"c":21,"f":2}, {"g":34,"c":2}];

const arrayCommonElements = (arr1, arr2) => {
    const counts = {};
    [...arr1, ...arr2].forEach(e => counts[e] = counts[e] ? counts[e] + 1 : 1);
    return Object.keys(counts).filter(e => counts[e] > 1);
}

let result = letters
.map(group => Object.keys(group))
.reduce((arr, v) => arr ? arrayCommonElements(arr,v) : v, null)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Reduced Time complexity to O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` loop and with one iteration of keys and maintain the `track` object to count the number of occurrences. After the iteration, if certain keys repeated to the count of elements mean that key exist in all.

```js
const commonKeys = (arr) => {
  const track = {};

  arr.forEach((obj) =>
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(
      (letter) => (track[letter] = (track[letter] ?? 0) + 1)
    )
  );
  return Object.keys(track).filter((letter) => track[letter] >= arr.length);
};

let letters = [
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 7 },
  { d: 4, c: 21, f: 2 },
  { g: 34, c: 2 },
];

console.log(commonKeys(letters));
```